# Regex word with '.'

Tags: c#, regex

I made a regex to find "RTE" word like `\bRTE\b`

This work fine at first and last position and middle of string.

I try to find RTE.(**WORD**) whit this `\bRTE\.\b` but this not working proprely.

Because it not supose to find in a string like this: "RTE.sa" and this is the only case that "work"

Comment: How it finds `RTE`. in `APP.sa`?

Comment: can you give a proper example please?...by what you are saying RTE in a string that does not contain it....

Comment: Sorry I make correction

Comment: Can you please paste exact regexp that you have so far and example string that it should and shouldn't match (but does)?

Comment: it works, see http://regex101.com/r/fZ8tU3/1

Comment: still.....place example where RTE should be found and where it should not.

Comment: ITs not suppose to find like this its supose to have the same patern like this \bRTE\b

Comment: Its a word , a word can not be stick to another character

Comment: the string or the pattern,because you say in your question "I try to find RTE. whit this \bRTE\.\b.A little code example would go a long way :)

Comment: if its not suposed to find why did you change the regex?

Comment: If \bBonjour\b   I not find when try "Bonjourdfskhjsdfkjhsdfkjsdh" So I not suppose to find whit "Bonjour.dsdsdsf""" with  \bBonjour\.\b

Comment: \b is a word boundary, a non-word character between two word characters counts as a word boundary which is why it is matching "RTE.sa"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` is a word boundary. That is why it is matching `RTE.sa`. After the `.`, you have the start of a word.

You are looking for the negated word boundary, which is `\B`.

So this regex should work: `\bRTE\.\B`